# Django views.py : unable to use vriable outside function

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I want a new page to open when a django form is filled- by hitting enter/by clicking on the 'Search' input and display results in that page using the data entered in the form.

*forms.py:*

```
class SearchBar(forms.Form):
    Search = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput)
```

The HTML page with the form looks like:

*index.html*

```
<form class="" action="result" method="post">
          
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form1.as_table }}

          <input class="Search" type="submit" name="" value="Search">

</form>
```

I want the submission of this form to open a new page: `result.html`

I have set the url of 'result' to the said HTML page:

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('result', views.result, name='result'),
]
```

I have extracted the data entered in the from by `form1.cleaned_data['Search']`.

```
form_input=form1.cleaned_data['Search']
```

However, once the result page is opened, it shows that the data (form_input) is not defined.
The following error is shown:

```
name 'form_input' is not defined
```

I am unable to use this data (form_input) in any other function of the `views.py` file.

*views.py*

```
def index(request):
    form1 = forms.SearchBar()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = forms.SearchBar(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            global form_input
            form_input= (form1.cleaned_data['Search'])

def result(request):
    print(form_input)
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I have even declared the variable `form_input` as a `global` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

**views.py**

```
from . forms import SearchBar

def search_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchBar(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_input = form.cleaned_data['Search']
            search_result = # your search query using the form_input variable
            return render(request, "result.html", {"search_result ": search_result })
```

If I understand corectly you would like to have your search bar in the **base.html** (base template that all other templates inherit from) then where your search bar in the template would be write something like this:

```
<form action={% url 'search_view' %} method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

And the **result.html** would look like this:

```
{% for item in search_result %}
    {{ i.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

Well, obviously the purpose of a search bar is to filter and display objects of a given model/models, for example if you had a `User` model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and wanted to filter objects based on your `user.name` then the the line of code would look something like this:

```
search_results = User.objects.filter(name__contains=form_input)
```

So that if you had for example 3 users with names like *Tom Jablinski*, *Tommy Joe* and *Jack White* (for example) and searched for **Tom** you would get a queryset containing 2 user objects: *Tom Jablinski* and *Tommy Joe* and they would be displayed in `result.html` temaplte.

Comment: What do you mean by "search_result = #your search query using the form_input variable" ? Yes so is the case..